# Run list of akka actors for list of messages

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to akka and I would like to run a list akka actors at once for a list of messages, for example (I'm using scala here):

input

```
message_1
message_2
message_3
```

output for each message:

```
1
2
3
```

Would run 3 akka actors at once passing each parameter from list to each of them, I would like to use those results later as a `List` of answers. Ideally I'm looking for operation that would give me following:

```
runActorsForListAndWaitForAnswer(messagesList).map(_.toInt()).sum
```

I don't know if such method exists, but it would be helpful. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all you have to abandon imperative, blocking mind-set. Akka tastes best when everything is asynchronous. You should never block, waiting for a reply of another actor. Instead you can take `Future[T]` object and apply a function on it. This function will be invoked *when* future is done.

Let's make an example: you have a `SquareActor` that takes an `Int` and returns a square of it. The correct way of asking it for a reply is:

```
squareActor ? 9 map {result =>
  println(result)  //81
}
//more code
```

Very important: code block with `println` won't block. *More code* will execute immediately and your callback method will be invoked some time later.

That being said we can start implementing your use case. If I understand correctly you have a list of actors and a list of integers. You want to send every integer to exactly one actor. Here is a pseudo code:

```
val actors: List[ActorRef] = //...
val numbers: List[Int] = //...
val actorsWithArguments: List[(ActorRef, Int)] = actors zip numbers
val futuresOfAny: List[Future[Any]] = actorsWithArguments map { case (actor, number) => actor ? number}
val futures: List[Future[Int]] = futuresOfAny map {_.mapTo[Int]}
val futureOfAllResults: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(futures)
val future: Future[Int] = futureOfAllResults map { _.sum}
```

I left explicit types intentionally to help you follow the code. Let's go step by step:

- `actorsWithArguments` is a `List` of tuples. Each item holds a pair of actor and a message - `(actor1, message1)`, `(actor2, message2)`, ...
- `futuresOfAny` contains a list of `Future` results of `actor ? number` invocation. `?` returns a `Future[Any]` because: a) result is not (yet) known and b) Akka doesn't know what the type of result will be (reply message)
- `futures` is strongly typed since we know that each reply is an `Int`. We `mapTo` each `Future[Any]` to `Future[Int]`
- `futureOfAllResults` employs really awesome transformation from a `List[Future[Int]]` to `Future[List[Int]]`. In other words we just turned list of future results into a single future result with all items.
- `future` holds (*will hold in the future*) your result.

If you think it's a lot of code, it was just for education purposes. Chaining and type inference can do magic:

```
val future = Future.sequence(actors zip numbers map { case (actor, number) => actor ? number} map { _.mapTo[Int]}) map { _.sum} }
```

Finally you got your result. Well, you *will get* in the future. Now if you want send that result back to another actor you say:

```
future map {sum => otherActor ! sum}
//or even...
future map otherActor.!
```

I **strongly** encourage you to read [chapter on Futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/futures.html) in the official documentation to make this all clearer.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! it takes a while to think in a more non-blocking way

Comment: @Wojtek: thanks!. Maybe start by reading some [tag:nodejs] tutorials (seriously!) where every I/O operation is non-blocking and requires asynchronous callback? Makes it easier to shift paradigms in Akka later.